# Why is my code constantly setting a variable to "true"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have opened the unity(2021.3.7f1) first person module, and tried to add an attack animation to it. I have discovered that my code as soon as it takes 1 input(click), it keeps taking that input. The "isAttacking" variable, keeps being set to "true", even when the player is not clicking. The debug there is how I have figured out this problem.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening, please help.

Under StarterAssets

```
        public class StarterAssetsInputs : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [Header("Character Input Values")]
            public Vector2 move;
            public Vector2 look;
            public bool jump;
            public bool sprint;
    
            [Header("Movement Settings")]
            public bool analogMovement;
    
            [Header("Mouse Cursor Settings")]
            public bool cursorLocked = true;
            public bool cursorInputForLook = true;
    
            // I added this in vv
            public bool attack = false;
    
    #if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
            public void OnMove(InputValue value)
            {
                MoveInput(value.Get<Vector2>());
            }
    
            public void OnLook(InputValue value)
            {
                if(cursorInputForLook)
                {
                    LookInput(value.Get<Vector2>());
                }
            }
    
            public void OnJump(InputValue value)
            {
                JumpInput(value.isPressed);
            }
    
            public void OnSprint(InputValue value)
            {
                SprintInput(value.isPressed);
            }
    
            // I added this in vv
            public void OnAttack(InputValue value)
            {
                AttackInput(value.isPressed);
            }
    #endif
    
    
            public void MoveInput(Vector2 newMoveDirection)
            {
                move = newMoveDirection;
            } 
    
            public void LookInput(Vector2 newLookDirection)
            {
                look = newLookDirection;
            }
    
            public void JumpInput(bool newJumpState)
            {
                jump = newJumpState;
            }
    
            public void SprintInput(bool newSprintState)
            {
                sprint = newSprintState;
            }
            
            private void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
            {
                SetCursorState(cursorLocked);
            }
    
            private void SetCursorState(bool newState)
            {
                Cursor.lockState = newState ? CursorLockMode.Locked : CursorLockMode.None;
            }
    
            // I added this in vv
            private void AttackInput(bool newAttack)
            {
                attack = newAttack;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Under first-person controller

```
    private void Attack()
    {
        if (_input.attack)
        {
            Debug.Log("Debug " + debugNR);
            debugNR++;
            WeaponController attackState = weapon.GetComponent<WeaponController>();
            attackState.isAttacking = true;
        }
    }
```

Under weapon controller

```
    public class WeaponController : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
        public Animator animator;
    
        public bool isAttacking = false;
    
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            animator.SetBool("Attack", isAttacking);
        }
    
        public void Attack()
        {
            isAttacking = false;
            animator.SetBool("Attack", isAttacking);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: @ARC I cannot find a place where any of the "On_something_" functions are being called.  So i'm not sure if that's what's the problem.

Comment: If your reports are accurate, then I presume `attackState.isAttacking = true;` found in `Attack()` is the only place you are settings `isAttacking` to true.  Therefore, if `isAttacking` really ___"keeps being set to 'true'"___, we can conclude that `Attack` is being called repeatedly, and that `_input.attack` is true on more than one occasion.  Con you confirm this much is true using your debugger?  Or do you simply never set `isAttacking` to false, which means that it ___remains true___, as opposed to _"keeps being set to true"._

Comment: @Wyck 

`Debug.Log("Debug " + debugNR);
debugNR++; `

The output of this is "Debug " and an ever increasing number

Comment: I don't see your `Attack` method of the first person controller referenced (called) anywhere in the code you provided.  How is it hooked up to be called?

Comment: @Wyck It is just in `Update()` with everything else like `Move();` and `JumpAndGravity();`

Comment: `Update` naturally gets called repeatedly.  So then presumably the problem is that `_input.attack` is true when you expect it to be false?  I'm curious about `_input` whatever that is.

Comment: `private StarterAssetsInputs _input;`
Edit: attack is just a public boolean variable

Comment: My apologies I forgot to ping you last time, and it seems the thread has died, @Wyck

Comment: How does `OnAttack` get called?  How did you bind this in your input system?  Can you confirm that `OnAttack` gets called correctly (with a log message) and that it is being called once with `InputValue.isPressed` true and then again later with `InputValue.isPressed` false?  Some actions are configured as _true every frame_ and some can be _true only on the frame the button was pressed down_ - in which case you may not get the complementary event where `isPressed` is false. Check your input config / bindings.

Comment: @Wyck  

I don't know how Unity's New Input System calls "OnAttack". I confirmed it gets called using a debug message, it shown successfully only once per click. I apologise, but how am I supposed to call a log message using `InputValue.isPressed`, unity gives an error for me when I type only `InputValue.isPressed`? What should I check for in the config/bindings, as I fail to find anything out of order?

Comment: for second question, I set it as "Attack" with binding "Left Button" for mouse

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. by `InputValue.isPressed` I meant that you've implemented a function declared as `public void OnAttack(InputValue value)` the class name of the argument is `InputValue` and the property name is `isPressed`.  You've named the argument `value` so it would be `value.isPressed`, which is passed as an argument to `private void AttackInput(bool newAttack)`.  You would log either `value.isPressed` or `newAttack`.  If it only ever gets called once with `true` then you are only getting "button down" notification; and **not** also getting "button up" for your "attack" input.

Answer (score 0):

`_input.attack` must be set to false, as part of the attack function in the first person controller

The function was changed from:

```
    private void Attack()
    {
        if (_input.attack)
        {
            Debug.Log("Debug " + debugNR);
            debugNR++;
            WeaponController attackState = weapon.GetComponent<WeaponController>();
            attackState.isAttacking = true;
        }
    }
```

To:

```
    private void Attack()
    {
        if (_input.attack)
        {
            Debug.Log("Debug " + debugNR);
            debugNR++;
            WeaponController attackState = weapon.GetComponent<WeaponController>();
            attackState.isAttacking = true;
            _input.attack = false;
        }
    }
```